# Firebase Real Database Security Rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Looking to make my server more secure at this moment my Firebase Security Rules are

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

The above rule would allow anyone that has a user credential to change data. This would make the data insecure therefore what I am looking to do is change the security rule so that only the owners of the data are allowed to change their information. please note that my data structure on the real database has two nodes

Please see the attached image below

[image]

We just want to secure posts the code I am trying to run and it's not working

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is simulated read denied

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Instead of linking to documentation and to default rules, can you edit your question to show: 1) your rules, 2) the JSON they secure (as text, bno screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 3) the code that you're running against the JSON and rules, and that isn't working as expected.

Comment: I hoped the above code helped

Comment: What are you trying to read in that screenshot? What is the value of UID that you set?

Comment: I am trying to read the Unique ID generated by firebase for each user

Comment: Don't describe it, but show it. If you make the screenshot bigger, you should be able to show exactly what you're telling the rules playground to do, and what UID you're telling it to use.